# Animating screen over long image

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview

I have a very long image that I need the screen to hover over it from its beginning till end.

Any suggestions how to implement this?

Thanks,
Ilan

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the memory is enough to load the required bitmap you can just load the bitmap in background thread before displaying the required part of the bitmap on the visible ImageViewer object here is a sample code for off-screen bitmap processing

```
            class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
                private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
                private int data = 0;

                public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
                    // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage collected
                    imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
                }

                // Decode image in background.
                @Override
                protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
                    data = params[0];
                    return decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), data, 100, 100));
                }

                // Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
                    if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
                        final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
                        if (imageView != null) {
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, What is the memory limitation?

Comment: It varies depending on the available memory on the mobile device

Comment: Thanks, i figured it out. It was small enough to load in to the memory. I surrounded it with a horizontal scroll view and used objectAnimator for the animation. I will post my full answer soon.